# Word interop Inserting/Adding custom document properties to selection

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop

I'm trying to insert a customDocumentProperty through Word interop for c# but i cant find any how-to's. I can access the application and activeDocument properties but i have no clue where to insert the property.

Adding a new property works and changing the value does also work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Just fixed it myself,

you need to add it to the fields like this:

```
    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Fields.Add(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Range, Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldDocProperty, prop.Name, true);
```

it is probably not the best way to do so but it works :)